Why does performance differ due to differences in model architecture?
Case 1
import resnet

class ViT(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self, ...):
      self.backbone = resnet()
      ...
   def forward(self, x):
      x = self.backbone(x)
      x = ...
      return x
   ...

Case 2
clas Multi_model(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self, ...):
      self.ViT = ViT()
      self.backbone = resnet()

   def forward(self, x):
      x = self.resnet(x)
      x = self.ViT(x)
      return x

Why do these two performance differences occur? In Case 1, we declare a CNN model inside the ViT class and add it to the Forward function. In Case 2, we declare ViT and CNN models separately inside a class called Multi_model and add them to Forward individually. My experimental results show that Case 1 has a 1-MAE performance of 0.91, while Case 2 has a 1-MAE performance of over 0.95. What's the difference, and is Case 2 incorrect?
Why do these two performance differences occur? In Case 1, we declare a CNN model inside the ViT class and add it to the Forward function. In Case 2, we declare ViT and CNN models separately inside a class called Multi_model and add them to Forward individually. My experimental results show that Case 1 has a 1-MAE performance of 0.91, while Case 2 has a 1-MAE performance of over 0.95. What's the difference, and is Case 2 incorrect?

Have you determined the different setup is in fact the cause of the variance? Performance could be impacted by different initializations, different ordering of data batches, randomness from dropout and other sources, etc.
